# split entries by field content in xml

Tags: xml

After a data-entry blunder, I have XML that looks a bit like this:

```
<lift>
  <header> ... </header>
  <entry>
    <lexical-unit>
      <form lang="grt"><text>Apdala /Apanga</text></form>
    </lexical-unit>
    <trait  name="morph-type" value="phrase"/>
    <sense>
      <definition>
        <form lang="hi"><text>स्वयं</text></form>
      </definition>
    </sense>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    ...
  </entry>
  ⋮
</lift>
```

Where there is a forward slash in the `text` element under `<form lang="grt">` I want to split this field on the slash (and trim whitespace) and create a whole new `entry` element duplicating the rest of the content of the entry element, but with, in the case above, `Apalda` as the text for one entry and `Apanga` as the text for the other. There may be no forward slash, in which case leave the entry as is, or more than one, in which case make a new `entry` for each token of that string.

I don't mind what language or script I use to do this, but it would be nice not to have to download any large frameworks, etc. This is one-off job and don't expect to have to do this again. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and have common developer tools already installed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @PaulCrovella. You're right of course, I was being a bit lazy and trying to use SO as a shortcut. I've managed to solve it now with Python and posted my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in python

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
from copy import deepcopy
tree = etree.parse('my xml file')
root = tree.getroot()
entries = root.findall('entry')
for entry in entries:
    problem_string = entry.find('lexical-unit').find('form').find('text').text
    tokens = problem_string.split('/')
    for token in tokens:
        entry.find('lexical-unit').find('form').find('text').text = token.strip()
        if token != tokens[-1]:
            entry = deepcopy(entry)
            root.append(entry)
tree.write('my parsed xml file', 'UTF-8')
```

it locates the problem string and splits it on the slash, then, for each token, strips it and inserts it back into the same place in the entry, creating deep copies of the entry as it goes.